# How can we move a UILabel to the new point, like the transitions of powerpoint?

Tags: swift, animation, frame, cgrect

When we use this one:

```
Do.frame =  CGRect (x:new x, y: new y, width: new width, height: new height)
```

it jumps to the new point. I want something animated.

Comment: just also have a look at: https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { 
      Do.frame =  CGRect (x:new x, y: new y, width: new width, height: new height)
  })
```

Of course, I don't think that compiles, but you get the idea.